# JavaScript : displaying Yesterdays Date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to display Yesterday Date on click of the button , but why its showing Date as "`2013-6-0`"
instead of `2013-05-31`

Could anybody please tell me what i was doing wrong

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function displayDate()
{

var d = new Date();
var curr_date = d.getDate()-1;
var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1;
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
var yesterday = curr_year + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_date ;

document.write(yesterday);

}
</script>
</head>
<body>


<p id="demo">Click Button to Display Yesterday Date</p>

<button type="button" onclick="displayDate()">Display Date</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `d.getDate()` is 1, and `1 - 1 = 0`, so what do you expect if not 0? You have to subtract 1 from the entire date, not just from the day-inside-the-month part.

Comment: Why are you adding 1 to the month?

Comment: @ExplosionPills well that'd be the right thing to do if it weren't being done at the wrong time :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should update and then reference the date from which you've subtracted 1 day:

```
var d = new Date();

d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1); // <-- add this to make it "yesterday"

var curr_date = d.getDate(); // <-- don't subtract 1 anymore
var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1;
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Gd5as/2/)**

Comment: Right ... and *then* get the pieces of the date for display.

Answer (score 1):

Your code simply takes a day number (like 1, 2, ...) and subtracts one from it.  Why would you expect that to automatically roll the day back to the previous month?

You can generate new dates by subtracting milliseconds from a given date.  Try this:

```
var today = new Date();
# subtract milliseconds representing one day from current date
var yesterday = new Date(today - 24*60*60*1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var today = new Date();
var yesterday = new Date();
yesterday.setDate(today.getDate()-1);

var yesterdayStr = yesterday.getFullYear() + "-" + (yesterday.getMonth()+1) + "-" + yesterday.getDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function displayDate()
{
    var today = new Date();
    today.setDate(today.getDate()-1);
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear().toString();
    var mm = (today.getMonth()+1).toString();         
    mm = mm.length==2?mm:"0"+mm;
    var dd = today.getDate().toString();
    dd = dd.length==2?dd:"0"+dd;
    var yesterday = yyyy+"-"+mm+"-"+dd;

    document.write(yesterday);
}
```